# Why is she saying “bang him on the counter” when he is a small living thing?

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context

It says on a dictionary that ‘bang’ means to hit violently or noisily. However, I think the following *bang* means merely put or place because the object is a rat and because Ron ‘placed him’ after the witch’s words.

But why is she saying “bang” in this situation?

(Ron is talking with the consultant witch of a magical pet shop.)

> ”It’s my rat,” he told the witch. “He’s been a bit off-color ever since I brought him back from Egypt.”
>
> ”Bang him on the counter,” said the witch, pulling a pair of heavy black spectacles out of her pocket.
>
> Ron lifted Scabbers out of his inside pocket and placed him next to the cage of his fellow rats, …(*Harry Potter 3* [US Version]: p.58)

Comment: Whew! Glad to see the context here. I was not looking forward to having to describe the off-color meaning of "bang". :-)

Comment: @T.E.D.: Your image only gets worse when you realize the thing to be "banged" is a rat.

Comment: Well it's .. a joke, kind of a joke.  In AmE identically you could say "throw your cat up here on the counter!" - of course you wouldn't literally do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To an American, "bang" can only mean to put something somewhere with destructive force.   To a Brit, however, "bang" can make to put something somewhere casually, without much effort or attention.  I once heard a Englishwoman say she intended to "bang up some wallpaper" (an American would have said "throw" in the same context).

Comment: Divided by a common language: "throw up some wallpaper" in Britain would invite the question "Why did you eat it in the first place?"

Comment: That was Bang On!

Comment: Err...there is actually another meaning of "bang" in American English...

Comment: @TimLymington: when I first encountered the phrase "throw up" some time in the seventies, it was an Americanism.

Comment: In American English slang, "bang" means *copulate* and "bang up" means *to impregnate*.  With that in mind, you might *bang* your spouse on the counter, but never a rat.  Also, you can *bang up* some *wallflower* but it would be impossible to *bang up* some *wallpaper*.

Comment: @T.E.D. -- "'Bang', 'screw', 'nail', it's not sex, it's carpentry." -- Rita Rudner (?)

Comment: @oosterwal -- "bang up" doesn't mean impregnate; the phrase is " *knock* up".

Comment: @Malvolio:  *Bang up* has multiple meanings in slang, one of them is *to impregnate*.  For instance, see:  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bang+up

Comment: Also to be banged up is to be imprisoned.
eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banged_Up_Abroad

Answer (score 4):

> verb /baNG/
>
> Strike or put down (something) forcefully and noisily, typically in anger or in order to attract attention
>
> - he began to bang the table with his fist
> - **Sarah banged the phone down**
> - someone was banging on the door

However in Britain it just means to put something down (casually as Malvolio suggested).
Typical expression: *Just bang it in the corner there*

I would like to think, that the author is referring to the [Dead parrot sketch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vuW6tQ0218) from Monty Python

PS: Bung has the same meaning in British slang: *Bung it on the table*

Comment: A Monty Python reference in Harry Potter? Interesting.

Comment: @Joachim: as an Easter egg, maybe?

Comment: I don't like it.  I know Harry Potter is part of the literary canon now so I can't say "it's wrong" but I don't think I've heard this before.  *Bung* sounds much more natural.  Alternatively *pop him on the counter* is a much more pleasant way of saying it.